# Threads and local proxy in Werkzeug. Usage

Tags: python, import, flask, werkzeug

At first I want to make sure that I understand assignment of the feature correct. The local proxy functionality assigned to share a variables (objects) through modules (packages) within a thread. Am I right?

At second, the usage is still unclear for me, maybe because I misunderstood an assignment. I use Flask. If I have two (or more) modules: A, B. I want to import object C from module A to module B. But I can't do it in the usual way, `from A import C`, because it will cause a looped import and thereafter ImportError. How to solve this issue with Werkzeug Local Proxy? And should I do it with Werkzeug?

module A:

```
from werkzeug.local import LocalSomething # LocalProxy or LocalStack

C = 'C'
# Somehow add C to LocalSomething
```

module B:

```
from werkzeug.locla import LocalSomething

C = LocalSomething()['C']
```

Comment: don't see an import loop here

Comment: I do not want to show all the situation because it is does not apply to the question topic. Please just imagine it has import loop.

Comment: you need to place a `Local` instance somewhere in a module and write/read to/from its attributes anywhere in your process/thread/greenlet. But you need to be able to import that instance in the first place

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Module Z:

```
from werkzeug.local import Local
myLocals = Local()
```

module A:

```
from Z import myLocals
myLocals.C = "C"
```

module B:

```
from Z import myLocals
C = getattr(myLocals, "C", None)
```

is this you're looking for?